# (SQL) UPDATE all column data by specific time

Tags: sql

i want update data from dcpecific time,from my db without update one by one from each rows.so how to update from specific "time" column if the 'time' column from (07.00.00-08.00.00) will show 'attandence' in all 'info' column.and if time (17.00.00-19.00.00) will show 'go home' in all "info" column,so not update one by one rows.

heres my db:

```
id  nama    time        info
1   Alfred  07.00.00    attandence
2   Tom     07.00.00    attandence
3   Tomi    07.40.00    NULL
4   ana     07.50.00    NULL
5   ana     17.50.00    go gome
6   andy    07.50.00    A
```

ive try by using upadate data but just for one single data time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code depends on database you use; the `sql` tag represents the *language*, but databases have their *flavors* and (usually) don't follow the standard.

In your case, the `time` column might be questionable because we don't know what it is - is it a string (one of `char` datatypes), `date` (with only time portion presented) or ... so you might need to apply certain function(s) to it so that values are correctly interpreted.

Though, general approach might involve the `case` expression. This is just an example of a query - adjust it so that it actually works in your database.

```
update your_table set
  info = case when time between '07.00.00' and '08.00.00' then 'attandence'
              when time between '17.00.00' and '19.00.00' then 'go home'
         end;
```

Comment: i use SQL Server actually but it seems work well, i try use SQL language same as used on MYSQL aslo.

Comment: OK; I'm glad you made it work!

Answer (score 0):

Just this Code

```
Update [tableName] set info = 'go home' where time between '17:00:00'  and '19:00:00'
```